# How can I replace a character in a string that the user inputs without using the replace method?

Tags: java

The program asks the user for a phrase and then asks which character it wants to replace and with what. The only string methods I can use are length, concat, +, charAt, substring, and equals (or equalsIgnoreCase).
I am very lost.

Comment: Start with an empty output string. Then go through that source string character by character (using `length()` and `charAt()`). For each character, either concatenate the character or its replacement to the output string.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done simply using `String::charAt` and concatenation operator `+`

```java
public static String replace(String str, char old, char replacement) {
    if (null == str || str.isEmpty()) {
        return str;
    }
    String replaced = "";
    for (int i = 0, n = str.length(); i < n; i++) {
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        replaced += c == old ? replacement : c;
    }
    return replaced;
}
```

---

**Update**

A recursive solution using `substring`, `charAt` and concatenation `+` is shown below.  It may use less concatenations and creation of new String instances if `old` character is relatively rare in the input string.

```java
public static String replace(String str, char old, char change) {
    if (null == str || str.isEmpty()) {
        return str;
    }
    int pos = 0;
    int n = str.length();
    
    while (pos < n && str.charAt(pos) != old) pos++;
    
    return pos == n ? str : str.substring(0, pos) + change + replace(str.substring(pos + 1), old, change);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay assume str is the string that was entered and c is the character that it needs to be replaced with. This should be some code that works:

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  if (str.charAt(i) == c) {
    if (i+1 <= str.length) str = str.substring(0, i-1) + str.substring(i+1, str.length);
    if (i+1 > str.length) str = str.substring(0, i-1);
  }
}
```

Your answer is now held in the str value.

Comment: You forgot to add replacement character into result

Comment: The code won't compile because `String.length()` is a method

Answer (score 0):

Сan you use StringBuilder?

```
String str = "something o";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
  if (str.charAt(i) == 'o') {
    sb.setCharAt(i, '.');
  }
}
System.out.println(sb);
```

Comment: sadly no I can't use StringBuilder or arrays

Answer (score 0):

> How can I replace a character in a string that the user inputs without using the replace method?

This works very simply by splitting the string via substring at the character and inserting the replacement.  Upper and lower of the same character are considered different characters.

```
SString test = "s - characters start, within, and end of string - s"; 
test = replace(test, 's','x');
System.out.println(test);
```

prints

```
x - characterx xtart, within, and end of xtring - x
```

The method

```
public static String replace(String s, char target, char replacement) {
     Objects.requireNonNull(s);
     for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
         if (s.charAt(i) == target) {
             s = s.substring(0,i) + replacement + s.substring(i+1);
         }
     }
     return s;
}
```